# Java Pointing to a random variable

Tags: java, string, random, label

I may be missing something obvious here, however using Labels in libgdx which take a string for the text to display I'm having trouble pointing a a random String.

```
String Movie1 ="The Shawshank Redemption (1994)";
String Movie2="The Godfather (1972)";
String Movie3="The Godfather: Part II (1974)";
String Movie4="The Dark Knight (2008)";
String Movie5="Pulp Fiction (1994)";

randomNumber = random.nextInt(5) + 1;

MovieName= new Label(String,style)
```

What would I put in for string to point to correspond the randomNumber to the appropriate movie. I can't put in "Movie" + randomNumber because it would just say "Movie5" not the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should put your Strings into an array of String or a collection such as an `ArrayList<String>`, and only then can you select a random one via a random index number.

e.g.,

```
Random random = new Random();
String[] movies = {"The Shawshank Redemption (1994)",
   "The Godfather (1972)",
   "The Godfather: Part II (1974)",
   "The Dark Knight (2008)",
   "Pulp Fiction (1994)"};


// later somewhere else in a method or constructor...
int randomNumber = random.nextInt(movies.length);
String randomMovieTitle = movies[randomNumber];
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you trying to do something like: `String s = Movie + randomNumber` to get a variable name `Movie1`, `Movie2`, etc.? This is not possible unless the variables are all attributes of a particular class. Regardless, you should not attempt to do this. Instead, you should use an array or a `List<String>` to hold the variables. You could do something like this:

```
String[] movies = {"The Shawshank Redemption (1994)",
    "The Godfather (1972)",
    "The Godfather: Part II (1974)",
    "The Dark Knight (2008)",
    "Pulp Fiction (1994)"}

int randomNumber = random.nextInt(movies.length);

String myMovie = movies[randomNumber];
```

Comment: actually it's possible, just not wise :-)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels if they're class attributes via reflection?

Comment: @Leo In the original question, they were not class attributes. I'm editing my answer to reflect this (no pun intented).

Comment: @Leo: I respectfully retract.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels no, I am who respect you and your long contribution to this community :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a switch statement for example:

```
var result;
randomNumber = random.nextInt(5) + 1;

switch(randomNumber) {
    case 1:
        result = Movie1;
        break;
    case 2:
        result = Movie2;
        break;
    case 3:
        result = Movie3;
        break;
}
```